# DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis", Failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known with Actix, Redis and Docker

Tags: docker, rust, redis, actix-web

I use Actix and Redis with Docker Compose.

Here is `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    image: actixblog
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      redis_server:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - redis-net
  redis_server:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    networks:
      - redis-net
networks:
  redis-net:
```

I use a `.env` file on runtime, it gets copied on Docker image I have built. The environment variable is this:

```bash
REDIS_URL="redis://redis_server:6379"
```

However, I get this error while logging continuously:

```
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actixblog::db][DEBUG] Creating connection manager for redis...
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][mio::poll][TRACE] registering event source with poller: token=Token(1), interests=READABLE | WRITABLE
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::builder][INFO] Starting 4 workers
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::server][INFO] Actix runtime found; starting in Actix runtime
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::worker][TRACE] starting server worker 0
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][mio::poll][TRACE] registering event source with poller: token=Token(0), interests=READABLE | WRITABLE
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::worker][TRACE] starting server worker 1
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::worker][TRACE] Service "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" is available
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][mio::poll][TRACE] registering event source with poller: token=Token(0), interests=READABLE | WRITABLE
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::worker][TRACE] starting server worker 2
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::worker][TRACE] Service "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" is available
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][mio::poll][TRACE] registering event source with poller: token=Token(0), interests=READABLE | WRITABLE
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::worker][TRACE] starting server worker 3
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::worker][TRACE] Service "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" is available
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][mio::poll][TRACE] registering event source with poller: token=Token(0), interests=READABLE | WRITABLE
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][mio::poll][TRACE] registering event source with poller: token=Token(0), interests=READABLE
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::worker][TRACE] Service "actix-web-service-127.0.0.1:8080" is available
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][actix_server::signals][TRACE] setting up OS signal listener
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][tokio_util::codec::framed_impl][TRACE] flushing framed transport
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:15][tokio_util::codec::framed_impl][TRACE] framed transport flushed
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:18][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis" err: Resolver(Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known" })
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:18][actix_redis::redis][ERROR] Can not connect to redis server: Failed to resolve hostname
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:18][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis" err: Resolver(Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known" })
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:18][actix_redis::redis][ERROR] Can not connect to redis server: Failed to resolve hostname
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:18][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis" err: Resolver(Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known" })
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:18][actix_redis::redis][ERROR] Can not connect to redis server: Failed to resolve hostname
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:18][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis" err: Resolver(Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known" })
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:18][actix_redis::redis][ERROR] Can not connect to redis server: Failed to resolve hostname
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:19][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:19][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:19][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:19][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:22][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis" err: Resolver(Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known" })
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:22][actix_redis::redis][ERROR] Can not connect to redis server: Failed to resolve hostname
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:22][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis" err: Resolver(Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known" })
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:22][actix_redis::redis][ERROR] Can not connect to redis server: Failed to resolve hostname
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:22][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis" err: Resolver(Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known" })
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:22][actix_redis::redis][ERROR] Can not connect to redis server: Failed to resolve hostname
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:22][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: failed to resolve host "redis" err: Resolver(Custom { kind: Uncategorized, error: "failed to lookup address information: Name or service not known" })
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:22][actix_redis::redis][ERROR] Can not connect to redis server: Failed to resolve hostname
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:23][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:23][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:23][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
web_1           | [2022-09-19][22:54:23][actix_tls::connect::resolver][TRACE] DNS resolver: resolving host "redis"
```

Why can't `actix_tls` resolve `redis`?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Rust 1.62.1
- Actix Web 4.1.0
- Docker 20.10.14

Comment: You should avoid underscores in domain names. They are not allowed by [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5). Consider using a hyphen instead (`redis-server`).

Comment: Changed to hyphen, didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [RedisActorSessionStore](https://docs.rs/actix-session/latest/actix_session/storage/struct.RedisActorSessionStore.html) in `actix-session` does not accept Redis URL starting with `redis://` for some reason.

```
# instead of this
redis://redis-server:6379

# use this
redis-server:6379
```

If you are getting your Redis URL from `.env` variable, and need to keep the `redis://` part, you can replace string:

```rust
let redis_url = env::var("REDIS_URL")
    .expect("Could not get `REDIS_URL` envar.")
    .replace("redis://", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `redis-server:6379` you can also use the `redis://<IPAddr>:6379`. You have to use the IP Address that is assigned to the host's `docker0` interface which you can get with:

`$ docker network inspect bridge --format='{{json .IPAM.Config}}'` 
The address is usually `172.17.0.1`.